# Flot chart plots new point in the end when data is changed

Tags: jquery, angularjs, flot

I'm using the following flot chart directive:

```
/**=========================================================
 * Module: flot.js
 * Initializes the Flot chart plugin and handles data refresh
 =========================================================*/

(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.charts')
        .directive('flot', flot);

    flot.$inject = ['$http', '$timeout'];
    function flot ($http, $timeout) {

        var directive = {
          restrict: 'EA',
          template: '<div></div>',
          scope: {
            dataset: '=?',
            options: '=',
            series: '=',
            callback: '=',
            src: '='
          },
          link: link
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
          var height, plot, plotArea, width;
          var heightDefault = 220;

          plot = null;

          width = attrs.width || '100%';
          height = attrs.height || heightDefault;

          plotArea = $(element.children()[0]);
          plotArea.css({
            width: width,
            height: height
          });

          function init() {
            var plotObj;
            if(!scope.dataset || !scope.options) return;
            plotObj = $.plot(plotArea, scope.dataset, scope.options);
            scope.$emit('plotReady', plotObj);
            if (scope.callback) {
              scope.callback(plotObj, scope);
            }

            return plotObj;
          }

          function onDatasetChanged(dataset) {
            if (plot) {
              plot.setData(dataset);
              plot.setupGrid();
              return plot.draw();
            } else {
              plot = init();
              onSerieToggled(scope.series);
              return plot;
            }
          }
          scope.$watchCollection('dataset', onDatasetChanged, true);

          function onSerieToggled (series) {
            if( !plot || !series ) return;
            var someData = plot.getData();
            for(var sName in series) {
              angular.forEach(series[sName], toggleFor(sName));
            }

            plot.setData(someData);
            plot.draw();

            function toggleFor(sName) {
              return function (s, i){
                if(someData[i] && someData[i][sName])
                  someData[i][sName].show = s;
              };
            }
          }
          scope.$watch('series', onSerieToggled, true);

          function onSrcChanged(src) {

            if( src ) {

              $http.get(src)
                .success(function (data) {

                  $timeout(function(){
                    scope.dataset = data;
                  });

              }).error(function(){
                $.error('Flot chart: Bad request.');
              });

            }
          }
          scope.$watch('src', onSrcChanged);

        }
    }


})();
```

When the data is set, it works fine. But in case the data is changed, and theres a new point, which is supposed to be put in the beginning, it gets plotted in the end. Due to this, the end point and the start point get connected.

eg.
Previous data: B-C-D-E-F
**Button Click**
New data: A-B-C-D-E-F
Chart : B-C-D-E-F-A (also, B and A get connected)

If the page is refreshed, the everything gets plotted properly. So the data and options are correct.
I don't know how to reset it, as all the code I saw is of canvas, placeholder and `$.plot()`.

Here's my data:
**Old:**

```
[{"label":"temp","data":[["2016-04-01T09:19:31.750Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:31.956Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:32.150Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:32.326Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:32.664Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:32.844Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:33.034Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:33.225Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:33.414Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:33.571Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:33.748Z","25"]]}]
```

**New:**

```
[{"label":"temp","data":[["2016-03-28T09:19:31.062Z","20"],["2016-04-01T09:19:31.750Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:31.956Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:32.150Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:32.326Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:32.664Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:32.844Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:33.034Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:33.225Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:33.414Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:33.571Z","25"],["2016-04-01T09:19:33.748Z","25"]]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a workaround,
Added a `reset` key in the directive's scope. I change it to true when the button is pressed, and then the `init()` is called again when the data is changed.

If there's even better option, please suggest.

```
var directive = {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: '<div></div>',
    scope: {
        dataset: '=?',
        reset: '=',
        options: '=',
        series: '=',
        callback: '=',
        src: '='
    },
    link: link
}; 

...

function onDatasetChanged(dataset)
{
    if (plot && !scope.reset)
    {
        plot.setData(dataset);
        plot.setupGrid();
        return plot.draw();
    }
    else
    {
        scope.reset = false;
        plot = init();
        onSerieToggled(scope.series);
        return plot;
    }
}
```